# Store json data in database field in laravel using $casts in model

Tags: php, laravel-5.6

I have `content(text)` field in database . I want to store `{"id" : 1}` in `content` field. but using casts instead of `json_encode`. How can I store it?
Any help would be appreciated. I am using `laravel 5.6`

Answer (score 1):

Hi You can do like this

1. Define Cast

__

```
$options["key"] = "value";

$yourarray->options = $options;

$yourarray->save();
```

That's All. Hope this will help you.

Comment: Sure. Keep it up. @unknown